# Lumen Custom Validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation, lumen

I am trying to implement a custom validation rule within lumen and I am following the docs for lumen 5.6. It says to refer to laravel validation to see how to use the validation. I am currently trying to make a validation to check if the value is a true null or not. So $x === "" would mean it fails Here is my rule located in App\Rules folder I created.

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class TrueNull implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        if($value === "") {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute cannot be an empty string.';
    }
}
```

I copied this straight from lumen docs and make my modification to the passes function. Within my modal have

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Lumen\Auth\Authorizable;
use App\Rules\TrueNull;
use Validator;
```

Then

```
public function validate($data)
{
    // make a new validator object
    $v = Validator::make($data, 
    [
        'x' => ['regex:/^(?=.+)(?:[1-9]\d*|0)?(?:\.\d+)?$/', new TrueNull]
    ]
}
```

But the validation for TrueNull never happens am I missing a connection or something its really frustrating because the docs says this should work.
Here is my controller calling the update I am validating.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        /*
            In middleware need to add community id to request.
        */
        try {
            $site = Site::findOrFail($id);

            if ($site->validate($request->all())) {
                $site->fill($request->all());

                // save
                $site->save();
            } else {
                return response()->json($site->errors(), 422);
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response()->json($e, 422);
        }

        return response()->json($site, 200);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe it would be solution for you to add the `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware that is available in Laravel ([see here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php))? This would not only allow you to remove the additional validation, it could also come in handy from a usability standpoint.

Comment: I dont want to perform any data manipulations within my api. I want to reject any non string field that is sending "" instead of null. I want to force our front ends to send correct data instead of just assuming because "" mean different things at my work.

Comment: Ok, then back to your question. I'm not entirely sure how the validator in lumen handles multiple validation rules (i.e. fail-on-first-error or evaluate-all), but in my opinion your regex already rules out empty strings. So maybe if you invert the order of the validation rules in the array, you can get it to fail for empty strings by the other rule?

Comment: I thought the same thing and I removed the regex and just left the validation rule in place and it still doesnt evaluate the "". It is weird it seems like in lumen if the request has the key but the attribute is "" it just skips everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For future reference I found a random snippet of code that offset the basic docs of Lumen. In my class for TrueNull instead of implements Rule I changed this to implements ImplicitRule and changed the use to \ImplicitRule and it is now catching that "" is not a null.

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ImplicitRule;

class TrueNull implements ImplicitRule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        if($value === "") {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute cannot be an empty string.';
    }
}
```

Comment: That's interesting, thanks for posting the solution! I have a remark on your implementation though: the name `TrueNull` implies for me that only `null` passes the test and empty strings as well as filled strings do not. In the current implementation, only empty strings don't pass, though. So you might want to change it to: `return $value === null;`

Comment: Thats a good idea thanks for the update! I will add that to my validation.

Comment: How can I use it in Lumen 5.3 where the contracts are different and no useful help from the documentation!

Comment: usage example:
```
$this->validate($request, [
    "value" => ["required", new TrueNull()],
]);
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer is greate by @Alexander Beyers but it doesn't work for Lumen 5.3. Here is how to create organised custom rules for the Lumen 5.3.

**Create a Directory name Rules under app dir and Create the Following File:**

```
namespace App\Rules;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class AlphaSpace
{
    public static function validate(){
        //Extending the custom validation rule.
        Validator::extend('alpha_spaces', function ($attribute, $value) {
            // This will only accept alpha and spaces.
            // If you want to accept hyphens use: /^[\pL\s-]+$/u.
            return preg_match('/^[\pL\s]+$/u', $value);
        });
    }
}
```

**Open the file `resources/lang/en/validation` and add the following under the Custom Validation:** 
**Note:**(under the Custom Validation is only for maintenance)

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Custom Validation Language Lines
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify custom validation messages for attributes using the
| convention "attribute.rule" to name the lines. This makes it quick to
| specify a specific custom language line for a given attribute rule.
|
*/
'alpha_spaces' => 'The :attribute may only contain letters and spaces.',
```

**Call the rule in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider::boot():**

```
use HRM\Core\Rules\AlphaSpace;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot() {
        AlphaSpace::validate();
    }

// class will carry on with the stuffs!
```

Now you can use it anywhere you want to  like this:

```
'first_name' => 'required|alpha_spaces|min:3|max:50',
'last_name' => 'required|alpha_spaces|min:3|max:50',
```

Comment: Thanks, works with Lumen 6x. Just uncomment ``$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);``

Comment: If you're using lumen 6x, be sure to copy the resources/lang/en/validation file from a laravel 6 version into your lumen app then add your custom validation in there under a key called custom: 'custom' => [
        'attribute-name' => [
            'rule-name' => 'custom-message',
        ],
    ],
that's how it knows your custom validation rules. without this your error messages will no longer be in human readable form instead what you get for a required field would the "validation.required" instead of "the :attribute is required" where :attribute will bethe name of the request param

Answer (score 4):

`Version: Lumen 7.X`

First, declare your rule in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`.
Create a `boot()` with your rule method as following (I registered a rule for phone number).

```php
public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        app('validator')->extend('phone', function ($attribute, $value) {
            return preg_match('%^(?:(?:\(?(?:00|\+)([1-4]\d\d|[1-9]\d?)\)?)?[\-\.\ \\\/]?)?((?:\(?\d{1,}\)?[\-\.\ \\\/]?){0,})(?:[\-\.\ \\\/]?(?:#|ext\.?|extension|x)[\-\.\ \\\/]?(\d+))?$%i', $value) && strlen($value) >= 10;
        });

        app('validator')->replacer('phone', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
            return 'Phone number has wrong format.';
        });
    }
```

Different part in opposite of Laravel, and most important is, that `AppServiceProvider` is not registered in Lumen by default.

You need to go to `bootstrap/app.php` and uncomment following line:

```php
 $app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
```

Maybe you would like to do `composer dumpautoload`, just in case, but it should work without it.

Then, in your code:

```php
$validator = Validator::make(
   $request->all(),
   [ 
       'tel' => 'required|phone' 
   ],
   [ 
       'tel.required' => 'Phone is required', 
       'tel.phone' => 'Phone has wrong format'
   ]
);
```

That should be it!